# CoPay wallet won't open on my Phone

Tags: client, copay

My Copay Wallet won't open on my Android phone. When I tap on the app the Copay Logo comes up then the screen turns white.

My ohone is an android  not IOS.

Comment: The other comment is different than mine. I have Bitcioin in my account and I don't want to lose it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to open copay on another mobile phone and see if it gonna work, 
some countries may block access to bitpay servers which are few, to avoid country citizens using bitcoin.

if so, try to install some VPN software and try again. if still doesn't work, you have to open an issue here https://github.com/bitpay/copay/issues with more details about your mobile phone.

if you don't want to do so, you can install copay on your laptop or any other device and import your mnemonic phrase there.